# (Ex 3.13 Lam) Suppose R is a simple, infinite dimensional algebra over a field k. If V is left R module, then V as vsp over k is infinite dimensional.

Tags: ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

My approach: Since R is infinite dimensional over k, therefore the infinite basis are $(r_1,...r_i..)$. Let $r_i.v = w_i\in V$ (Since $V$ is a left $R$ module). Now I prove that $w_i$ are independent. Choose finite $w_i$ and let $c_1.w_1+ ...c_n.w_n = 0$. Then taking $v$ common, we have $(c_1.r_1 + ..c_nr_n).v = 0 \implies (c_1r_1 +...+c_nr_n)=0$. Since by choice $r_i$ are independent, therefore $c_i=0$ $\forall i$. Hence $w_i$ are all independent.

Nowhere in the proof I have used the fact that $R$ is simple, so I suspect my proof is wrong. Can someone help me criticize my proof and also provide some hint?

UPDATE: I think not all $c_i= 0$ is implied because there can exist zero divisior of $r_i$. Is this a valid objection

Comment: If $c.v=0$ and $v\neq 0$ then $c=0$. This argument does not work in general for modules over arbitrary rings. If the base ring happens to be a field then $Ann(v)$ is a two sided ideal and hence must be $0$.

Comment: @user2902293: So you are confirming my objection I posted in update.

Comment: @user2902293   and since R is simple, we have Ann(v) = 0; but I think I might get into trouble with regard to Ann_l(v) and Ann_r(v) (left annihilator and right annihilator)

Comment: No, your objection is not correct since the reason your argument is failing is not due to the presence of zero divisors.  The exercise is for simple rings so a particular special case is that of division rings which have no zero divisors.

Comment: @user2902293 Oh I understood, you were talking of this equation [c_1r_1 +..c_nr_n].m=0 (I though you were referring to the next equation). And my objection is invalid because base ring is a field, so such a situation (zero divisor case) will never arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: it must be assumed that $V$ is a nonzero module.

Suppose $V$ is a (nonzero) left $R$-module. Consider the map
$$
R\to\operatorname{End}_k(V)
$$
defined by the left multiplications, which is a $k$-algebra homomorphism and is injective because $R$ is simple. What would be the consequence if $V$ happens to be finite dimensional over $k$?